# JasperReports Server sending too many copies of the same email

Tags: unix, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am currently using the community edition of jasperReports Server 4.1.0 build 20110626_0015.

basically, I've built several templates that functioned as expected in our previous jasper installation (the one before all the blue UI stuff). Migrating them over to 4.1.0, particularly with reports that contain subreports and/or parameters, jasper is sending unpredictable quantities of separate emails with the identical report content. This has been anything from 2x the expected quantity to as many as 29!!! on a single send. THis seems like a bug.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem? if so, what was done to remedy the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing these properties in the `<tomcat_installation>/wepapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/js.quartz.base.properties` file:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 1200000
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=180000
```

Comment: Another quartz configuration that our ops team ended up trying (that I think has done the trick), as quoted from the user wiki: "Setting the org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered property in <js-install>/WEB-INF folder to FALSE should resolve the problem in non-clustered environment. In clustered environment the property should be set to TRUE."